# ASP.NET ObjectDataSource problem

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

This is the common structure of all of my classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get;set; }
    public string User_name { get; set; }
    public string Pass_word { get; set; }
    public string UserTypeCode { get; set; }

    public int SaveOrUpdate()
    {
        int id = -1;

        if (this._ID <=0)
        {
            id = this.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            bool success = this.Update();

            if(success)
            {
                id = this._ID;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Update failed!");
            }
        }

        return id;
    }

    private int Save() { }
    private bool Update() { }
    public static User Get(int id) { }
    public static List<User> Get() { }
    public bool Delete() { }
}
```

I was using these classes smoothly with winforms.

But while working with ASP.NET, when I try to configure the object data source for a GridView, I don't find the method-names in the `Data Source Configuration Wizard`. I.e. they are not showing up. So my methods became useless.

I can't change this general structure of all of my classes. I have also a code generator written for them. And I must use `ObjectDataSources`.

My first question is, why don't they show up?

And, what should I do to make them show up?

Comment: Could you post the code from the aspx page and/or code-behind? 
That might be more helpful in spotting errors.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I guess your saying you can't even get the tags configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectDataSources look for methods within the type specified that match the signature of the update/insert method name and the update/insert parameters provided.

Your `SaveOrUpdate` method is on an instantiated class, and the ObjectDataSource will not find a matching method signature.

From what you have, if you must use ObjectDataSources, you may want to consider using a wrapper method.  [Example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.update.aspx)

Comment: +1 from me. Signature is important. So my answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, but you can try to mark this class with [DataObjectAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataobjectattribute.aspx) and CRUD methods with [DataObjectMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataobjectmethodattribute.aspx). I did not use `ObjectDataSource` for ages, so can forget something.

Comment: I know, you need special signature.